# Google Cloud platform: Nifi UI doesn't works on External Address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-nifi

I created project on GCP.
Then I created VM with Debian 5.10.46-4.
Then I install Nifi 1.14.0.
In properties I see this:

web properties

For security, NiFi will present the UI on 127.0.0.1 and only be accessible through this loopback interface.
Be aware that changing these properties may affect how your instance can be accessed without any restriction.
We recommend configuring HTTPS instead. The administrators guide provides instructions on how to do this.

I open all port in firewall

nifi
Ingress
Apply to all
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
all
Allow
1000
default
Off

I what to work with UI on External IP like https://:8080/nifi/ my VM on GCP.
But I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Have you edited nifi.properties and changed https listen address to 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 1):

I would change the nifi.properties to make sure that the nifi.web.https.host or nifi.web.https.address is set to 0.0.0.0 and then restart NiFi. Without making this change, then NiFi will only listen on 127.0.0.1, which is done by default.

Also check to make sure that the applicable firewalls (host and GCP) allows traffic over the specific port mentioned for NiFi as necessary.

Comment: In conf/nifi.properties setting  nifi.web.https.host=0.0.0.0 and restart Nifi allowed login from remote laptop.  Prior to this change it was giving $ curl -v --insecure http://nifihost:18443/
* About to connect() to nifihost port 18443 (#0)
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* Connection refused

Comment: So then it worked?

Comment: Yes after setting 0.0.0.0 it worked to connect from remote laptop to separate Nifi server.

Comment: Awesome! Hopefully the answer gets marked as the chosen answer.